# jquery показывает вместо кирилицы иероглифы в Moizll'e и IE на html-странице, сгенерированной в php

Tags: php, html, jquery, unicode

Проблема с отображением русского шрифта в Moizll'e и IE.
Есть `php` страница. На ней присутствует раздвижное меню. При нажатии на элемент меню через `jquery` отображается содержимое, которое берётся из `html` файла.
Содержимое на кириллице отображается иероглифами, хотя остальной текст, который не подгружается из отдельного файла, отображается нормально. Причем проблема лишь в  Moizll'e и IE, в Опере и Хроме всё норм. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, ещё вопрос есть ли разница,когда я сохраняю в UTF-8 и UTF-8 with BOM ?

Answer (score 1):

проверь у файла `menu` кодировку желательно чтоб это была кодировка `utf-8`
а ещё неплохо было бы создать файл `.htaccess` на хостинге и добавить туда вот этот код:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

и помни все файлы должны быть с одной кодировкой иначе у тебя и будет такая путаница дальше

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, ещё вопрос есть ли разница,когда я сохраняю в UTF-8 и UTF-8 with BOM ?

Comment: да вариант 2 лучше так как первый не всегда срабатывает и на некоторых хостингах лагает

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: BOM (Byte Order Mark) – представляет из себя три нечитаемых символа, которые смещают ваши данные от начала файла.